# Where can I find older versions of GitLab Runner?

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab

I'm stepping through the documentation [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/linux-manually.html) for installing GitLab Runner. When I register the runner, I get this compatibility error:

```
ERROR: Checking GitLab compatibility... not-compatible  reason:=Gitlab
Runner >= 9.0 can be used ONLY with GitLab CE/EE >= 9.0 results=405 
runner=FsqqGSrw statusText=405 Method Not Allowed
```

We're operating on an isolated network with GitLab 8.13.0, and no plan to update at the moment. All I can find in the documentation is this [link](https://gitlab-ci-multi-runner-downloads.s3.amazonaws.com/latest/binaries/gitlab-ci-multi-runner-linux-amd64) which provides the latest 9.0 version of the runner.

Does anyone know where I might find older versions of GitLab Runner?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As described in the documentation [you are following](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/linux-manually.html) to install on the first paragraph:

> You can download a binary for every available version as described in
>   Bleeding Edge - download any other tagged release.

Following the link in this sentence allow your to find the [tag list page](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/tags)

Last version in 1.X (Hence compatible with 8.X versions of Gitlab is 1.11.2 at time of writing, you can download it from [The tag details page](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/repository/archive.zip?ref=v1.11.2)

If you prefer another archive format, you can choose in the dropdown of download at the right of the tag page description:

[image: Tags page view with drop down for download at right]

Comment: Hey, sorry I didn't had a better answer :) I've tried to be as descriptive as possible of the path I did follow to give you the keys for next time :)

Answer (score 1):

According to the [runner readme](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/blob/master/README.md), the old version compatible with 8.x can be [downloaded from here](https://gitlab-ci-multi-runner-downloads.s3.amazonaws.com/v1.11.2/index.html).